# Open Twitter app using Twitter Fabric kit Android

Tags: android, twitter

I've integrated twitter fabric kit for android.

i'm done with Login, Share.

All i want to open twitter app using fabric.

> FYI. I've gone through fabric sdk but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Did you get any callback when tweet is posted.. like success or failure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for sure.

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/"));
                context.startActivity(i);`

No need to extend url by intent.
this will open your twitter feed/web (in case app is not installed.)

> FYI this will not ask you to choose Twitter app / browse.